# how to control my 5D mark II using my computer

Tags: canon, canon-5d-mark-ii

I am trying to take a picture using my 5D mark II and controlling it from my laptop. I have done it a long time ago but cannot remember how.

Comment: Check the tethering tag: http://photo.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btethering%5d%20canon

And specifically these questions may help.  There is an EOS utility, CHDK, or you can use Lightroom.

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41593/how-can-i-control-a-dslr-camera-programmatically/41759#41759

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/is-it-possible-to-do-remote-capture-on-a-canon-eso400d

Comment: Hi Jim, and welcome to Photo.SE. What did you try already?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2766/15871 has the same answer. The camera models are different, but the software that is the answer is the same.

Comment: You can tether with Lightroom.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for software app called [Canon EOS Utility](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/eos_digital_slr_cameras/eos_5d_mark_ii#DriversAndSoftware).